# Need to ping 1000 urls every 2 minutes

Tags: php, javascript, python, perl, curl

I have 1000 feed urls sitting in a MySQL database table. I need to do a http request to all these urls every 2 minutes. I wrote a php script to do that, but the script takes 5min 30sec to run.

I want to be able to finish all the 1000 requests in under a minute. Is there a way to run multiple async processes to get the job done faster? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can see many of those feeds blocking you if you did this.

Comment: Make a script that pings one website, launch it 1000 times to create separate processes without blocking.

Comment: @Dagon - if he were hitting 1 feed 1000x in 2 minutes, yes.  But the OP has said only that he has 1000 (presumably different) URLs that he needs to hit every two minutes.  How often he repeatedly hits a single URL is a separate issue.

Comment: @broofa 1 particular feed every 2 minute is still excessive.

Comment: @Dagon - 1. we've been given no information about how often the OP expects to hit a particular feed.  2. "excessive" depends entirely on what service we're talking about, and how often the fetched data is expected to change.

Comment: "I need to do a http request to all these urls every 2 minutes." seems clear to me, every url every 2 minutes

Comment: Thanks, Alex Lunix for the suggestion. I looked it up and was pretty easy to implement into my code as I already had written some code in curl. See my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @Dagon.  whups... missed that part. :)  'Still not ready to concede it's excessive.  It's not hard to imagine feeds that update with more frequency than that. (e.g. twitter search feed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alex Lunix for the suggestion. I looked up curl_multi_* and found a solution to do it in curl, so I don't have to change my code much. But thank you all the others for the answers. Here is what I did:

```
<?php
require("class.php");
$obj=new module();

$det=$obj->get_url();

$batch_size = 40;

function curlTest2($urls) {
    clearstatcache();
    $batch_size = count($urls);

    $return = '';

    echo "<br/><br/>Batch:";
    foreach ($urls as &$url)
    {
        echo "<br/>".$url;
        if(substr($url,0,4)!="http") $url = "http://".$url;
        $url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=-1&q=".$url;
    }

    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

    $chs = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $batch_size; $i++)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        array_push($chs, $ch);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $batch_size; $i++)
    {
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
        curl_setopt($chs[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $urls[$i]);
    }

    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $batch_size; $i++)
    {
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chs[$i]);
    }

    $active = null;
    //execute the handles
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }

    //close the handles
    for ($i = 0; $i < $batch_size; $i++)
    {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chs[$i]);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
}

$startTime = time();
$urls = array();

foreach($det as $key=>$value){
    array_push($urls, $value['url']);

    if (count($urls) == $batch_size)
    {
        curlTest2($urls);
        $urls = array();
    }
}

echo "<br/><br/>Time: ".(time() - $startTime)."sec";
?>
```

This brought down my processing time from 332sec to 18sec. The code probably can be optimized a little but you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 7):

Since your question is about sending http requests, not really ping, you can use [`Grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) ([Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)+[gevent](http://www.gevent.org)) to do it *easily and fast (in my experience seconds for a couple hundred url requests)*:

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.python.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://www.google.com',
]
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)    # [<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>]
```

---

Your Php script takes 5 mins to run because it is synchronous code, which means that for every request you sent, you have to wait for response to arrive *before* moving onto sending the next request.

The trick here is not to *wait* (or block as many would call) for responses but go straight to make the next request, and you can achieve it easily with `gevent`(coroutine-based) or `nodejs`. You can read more on it [here](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/callbacks-promises-and-coroutines-oh-my-the-evolution-of-asynchronicity-in-javascript).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`AnyEvent::Ping`](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aPing) or [`AnyEvent::FastPing`](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aFastPing) modules on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/).

Below is straightforward example of using `AnyEvent::Ping` to ping 10000 urls:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Ping;

my $cv   = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $ping = AnyEvent::Ping->new;
my @results;

for my $url (get_ten_thousand_urls()) {
    $cv->begin;

    # ping each URL just once
    $ping->ping( $url, 1, sub {
        # [ url address, ping status ]
        push @results, [ $url, $_[0]->[0][0] ];
        $cv->end;
    });
}

$cv->recv;

# now do something with @results
```

Some quick tests of above using 10,000 *random* URLs all took just over 7 seconds to run on my Macbook Air.  With tweaking and/or using faster event loop then this time will drop further (above  used default pure Perl event loop).

NB. [`AnyEvent`](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent) is an abstraction library which will allow you to use the async event system provided by (or installed on) your system.  If you want to use a specific event loop then remember to install the relevant Perl module from CPAN, for e.g. [`EV`](https://metacpan.org/module/EV) if using `libev`.  `AnyEvent` will default to a pure Perl event loop if nothing else is found (installed).

BTW, If you just need to check an HTTP request (ie. not ping) then simply replace `AnyEvent::Ping` part with [`AnyEvent::HTTP`](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aHTTP).

Answer (score 3):

You tagged this with "python", so I'll assume that using Python is an option here. Look at the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import os
import requests
import subprocess

addresses = ['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.5', '4.2.2.1', '8.8.8.8']
null = open(os.devnull, 'w')

def fbstatus(count):
    """Returns the address, and True if the ping returned in under 5 seconds or
    else False"""
    return (count,
        requests.get('http://www.facebook.com/status.php').status_code)

def ping(address):
    """Returns the address, and True if the ping returned in under 5 seconds or
    else False"""
    return address, not subprocess.call(['ping', '-c1', '-W5', address],
        stdout=null)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(15)
if False:
    print pool.map(ping, addresses)
else:
    pool.map(fbstatus, range(1000))
```

### New - Fetching pages

The `fbstatus()` function fetches a page from Facebook. This scaled almost linearly with the size of the pool up through 30 concurrent processes. It averaged a total runtime of about 80 seconds on my laptop. At 30 workers, it took a total of about 3.75 wall clock seconds to finish.

### Old - Pinging

This uses the `subprocess` module to call the `ping` command with a 5 second timeout and a count of 1. It uses the return value of `ping` (0 for success, 1 for failure) and negates it to get `False` for failure and `True` for success. The `ping()` function returns the address it was called with plus that boolean result.

The last bit creates a multiprocessing pool with 5 child processes, then calls `ping()` on each of the values in `addresses`. Since `ping()` returns its address, it's really easy to see the result of pinging each of those addresses.

Running it, I get this output:

```
[('1.2.3.4', False), ('1.2.3.5', False), ('4.2.2.1', True), ('8.8.8.8', True)]
```

That run took 5.039 seconds of wallclock time and 0% CPU. In other words, it spent almost 100% of its time waiting for `ping` to return. In your script, you'd want to use something like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to fetch your feed URLs (and not the literal `ping` command that I was using as an example), but the basic structure could be nearly identical.

Comment: Yes, python was an option. But I ended up going the CURL route as I already had code in place and it was just easy to modify it. But thanks! I voted your answer up.

Comment: Glad we could help! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

You could try multithreading ping on python. 
Here is good example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
from Queue import Queue

num_threads = 4
queue = Queue()
ips = ["10.0.1.1", "10.0.1.3", "10.0.1.11", "10.0.1.51"]
#wraps system ping command
def pinger(i, q):
    """Pings subnet"""
    while True:
        ip = q.get()
        print "Thread %s: Pinging %s" % (i, ip)
        ret = subprocess.call("ping -c 1 %s" % ip,
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        if ret == 0:
            print "%s: is alive" % ip
        else:
            print "%s: did not respond" % ip
        q.task_done()
#Spawn thread pool
for i in range(num_threads):

    worker = Thread(target=pinger, args=(i, queue))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
#Place work in queue
for ip in ips:
    queue.put(ip)
#Wait until worker threads are done to exit    
queue.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Update**: Re-tested this with maxSockets = 100 and while connected to a *very* good network connection.  The script finished in < 1 second, meaning the biggest factor is probably network thruput / latency, as previously noted.  Your results will almost certainly vary. ;) ]

You can use node.js for this, as it's API for doing HTTP is powerful, clean, and simple.  E.g. The following script fetches ~1000 requests in <strike>10 seconds</strike> less than one second on my MacBook Pro:

**test.js**

```
var http = require('http');

// # of simultaneouse requests allowed
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100;

var n = 0;
var start = Date.now();

function getOne(url) {
  var id =  n++;
  var req = http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
      // do whatever with response data here
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
      console.log('Response #' + id + ' complete');
      n--;
      if (n == 0) {
        console.log('DONE in ' + (Date.now() - start)/1000 + ' secs');
      }
    });
  });
}

// Set # of simultaneous connections allowed
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  getOne('http://www.facebook.com/status.php');
}
```

Outputs ...

```
$ node test.js  
Response #3 complete
Response #0 complete
Response #2 complete
...
Response #999 complete
DONE in 0.658 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Perl's  [POE Ping Component](http://search.cpan.org/~rcaputo/POE-Component-Client-Ping-1.173/lib/POE/Component/Client/Ping.pm) module for this task quite extensively.